# Setting value for Publisher, Size, and Version in Win 7's Programs and Features for a Java app

Tags: java, windows-7, addremoveprograms

I have a Java application that is running on Windows 7. When I look at the uninstaller inside control panel>Programs and Features I see that other apps have values for Publisher, Size, and Version.

I would like to set these values in my application, but I do not know how.

Could any of you kind people please point me to an article or explain to me how I can accomplish this? I've done a bit of searching but I am not coming up with anything.

Thank you,

Mattimus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe another alternative is to add these values directly to the registry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't know how "best-practice" this is, but it's basically what the windows installer is doing.

Answer (score 3):

This come from .MSI files,  which are Windows Installer files.

If you want your Java application to be visible in Add/Remove programs you have to build an .MSI file.   These are usually built by installer tools  such as http://www.advancedinstaller.com/   which has Java support.

Microsoft provides free installer tool Wix http://wix.sourceforge.net/  which is slightly harder to use than the one above,  but it is free.